# CreateJS Cannot Read Property 'Get' - TweenJS Demo

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I was trying to set up the basic demo of Tween JS, and I'm receiving the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

JS

```
function init() {
        var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
        var circle = new createjs.Shape();
        circle.graphics.beginFill("Crimson").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        circle.x = 100;
        circle.y = 100;
        stage.addChild(circle);
        createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: true})
          .to({x: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
          .to({alpha: 0, y: 75}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
          .to({alpha: 0, y: 125}, 100)
          .to({alpha: 1, y: 100}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
          .to({x: 100}, 800, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
      }

window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```

Comment: Are you loading a TweenJS script? It is not part of EaselJS, so will have to be loaded separately.

Comment: @Lanny weird... I guess not.  I thought I was using a script that had the complete CreateJS Library as I planned on using the full library. I must have misread the CDN link I used. Can't believe I didn't notice this. I can't mark a comment as an answer though.

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lanny pointed out in the comments, my TweenJS script was not loading. It is not included with EaselJS - make sure to add the script to load the library.

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
```